# WIn32 api - 2 process write to console

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have an issue with write to the same console with two processes(1 parent create child process) that interacts between them with a pipe.
every process has multiple threads and has to write to the console.
sometimes I find that one process start to write and the other process stops it in the middle and writes in its place and so it turns out that the text is blurred.
of course, every process has his own semaphores for his own threads but the problem is between the two processes.

There is a way to fix this issue?

Comment: use mutex (*CreateMutex*) for example. thread before print to console - acquire mutex and then release it. but better - first format string and call `WriteConsole` only once - this is "atomic" output. it can not be mixed with another *WriteConsole*. look like you do several *WriteConsole* for atomic by sense print

Comment: This is work for threads in the same process but I have two process and that's when I have problem with the write to console

Comment: what is *This is work for threads in the same process* ?

Comment: @Anon1212: you need a named mutex, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa).